# Fresh Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS freezes randomly

Tags: 22.04, graphics, dell, freeze

I bought a refurbished dell latitude 7390 and decided to install ubuntu on it. This was my first time installing any linux distro. In the installation process, I had to do the installation in safe graphics mode because the normal installation would freeze in dell/ubuntu splash screen. In the safe graphics mode, the installation works without any problems.

Shortly after the installation, the freezing starts. I haven't found a pattern in what causes the freezing. Sometimes it freezes after as short as 5 seconds and I don't think I have gone longer than an hour without a freeze. During the freeze everything in the screen freezes including the cursor and it will stay that way until I do a hard reset with the power button. Some of the fn buttons stay responsive after the freeze so I can toggle the backlight of the keyboard during the freeze for example.

Some other remarks:

- Occasionally, I see some graphical glitches in the screen flashing quickly and sometimes right after that a freeze occurs.
- /var/crash is empty. I have tried to dig into the journalctl but can't really tell if somethings wrong there.
- I tried installing the OS with a different thumb drive but the behaviour is the same.
- Memtest runs without any errors.

Specs and model:

- Dell Latitude 7390
- Intel i5-8350U
- Intel UHD Graphics 620
- 16GB RAM
- 512GB NVMe SSD

uname -r => 6.5.0-25 generic

Anything tips on what I should try? Any other info that I should provide that might be relevant? All help is appreciated :)